# How to select exact value from sql statement

Tags: mysql, select, exact-match

I have multiple records that start with "She" like "shepherd", "shell", "shelf"... I want to return records that has "she" with

```
SELECT records FROM MYTABLE WHERE records = 'She'
```

However this returns all data mentioned above... how can I return just "she' without the rest of the data?

Comment: Is **she** the only word in the record or are there words after it?

Comment: Yes there are many words that begin with she... like shepherd, shell, shelf, sheer.. but my query should only return she

Comment: Have you tried 'SELECT records FROM MYTABLE WHERE records LIKE "She %"'

Comment: No I haven't.. it's actually a parameter that I am passing and thought it's not possible

Comment: `WHERE records = 'She'` will only return records where `records = 'She'`.  What do you mean "*this returns all data mentioned above*"?  That's not possible.  You must be omitting some information.

Comment: Hi eggyal... along with she, I get shepherd, sheer, shelf, sheep etc

Comment: Thanks eggyal... I have what I want... it's working now... my stored procedure was using %... that's why it gave me all the results... thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the records where the word beings with "She" the query should be:

```
SELECT records FROM MYTABLE WHERE records LIKE 'She %'
```

Comment: With the space at between the E and % it should ignore the words like shepherd, shell, shelf,etc.

Comment: doing that gave me no results socialrel8.. :(

Comment: Can you post an example of your database schema?

Comment: right now I am only using one table with two columns... records and recordsMeaning

Comment: Thanks socialrel8... apparentlly your answer was correct... it was my stored procedure that was doing exactly the opposite...

Comment: Great - I had just created a test DB to check it too! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

To just select the ones that start with "she" (will also select records that start with "shephard" etc):

```
  SELECT records FROM MYTABLE WHERE records LIKE 'she%'
```

The ones that have the word "she" in it:

```
  SELECT records FROM MYTABLE 
      WHERE records LIKE 'she %' OR 
            records LIKE '% she %' OR 
            records LIKE '% she'
```

You could perhaps use regular expressions as well.

Comment: doing this with my parameter like SET @myValue = RTRIM(@myValue) + '%'; still returns all the records

Comment: I really don't understand what you mean with "returns all the records". Could you elaborate on the records you have and show which ones you want and which you don't?

Comment: sure... I only want she.. but it's returning she, shepherd, sheer, shelf etc